# Evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x^2}{2}} e^{x-\frac{t^2}2}dt$ using the error function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Ok guys... I was playing around with math, and I've noticed one thing... Considering this integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x^2}{2}} e^{x-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt$$

It looks a lot like the [error function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). I was trying to manipulate it in a way to make it look like an error function, but I didn't find a way.

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: Make a change of variables to  $z=\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}$ and using $e^{x-\frac{t^2}{2}}= e^x e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$will help to see the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** Using 
$$\text{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^x e^{-u^2}du$$
you may write
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x^2}{2}} e^{x-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt&=e^{x}\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x^2}{2}} e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt\\\\
&=\sqrt{2}\:e^{x}\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x^2}{2\sqrt{2}}} e^{-u^2}du\\\\
&=\sqrt{2}\:e^{x}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{-u^2}du+\int_{0}^{\frac{x^2}{2\sqrt{2}}} e^{-u^2}du\right)\\\\
&=e^x \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{x^2}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)\right).
\end{align}
$$